# Create a GUI to update parameters of an Object

Tags: java, swing, form, event-handling

I have an `Glob` object which represents a glob of data. It has several parameters like size, the date it was created, who created it, and so on. I'm building a GUI to modify these `Globs` of data, and in my GUI is a `JTextField` for each of these parameters. Each `JTextField` has a `FocusListener` attached to it, which looks like:

```
public class GlobUpdaterGUI {

    HashMap<String, Glob> globs;

    // I know it's not great style to call main like this, but
    // it makes this snippet runnable. 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GlobUpdaterGUI();
    }

    public GlobUpdaterGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Glob Updater");
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250,150));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        JTextField globNumber = new JTextField(10);

        JTextField dateTextField = new JTextField(10);
        dateTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

                /* "globNumber" lets the user select a glob from "globs". */
                Glob glob = globs.get(globNumber.getText());

                glob.date = dateTextField.getText();
            }
        });

        JTextField sizeTextField = new JTextField(10);
        sizeTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                Glob glob = globs.get(globNumber.getText());

                glob.size = dateTextField.getText();
            }
        });

        JTextField creatorTextField = new JTextField(10);
        creatorTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                Glob glob = globs.get(globNumber.getText());

                glob.creator = dateTextField.getText();
            }
        });

        panel.add(new JLabel("Glob Number:"));
        panel.add(globNumber);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Glob Date:"));
        panel.add(dateTextField);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Glob Size:"));
        panel.add(sizeTextField);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Glob Creator:"));
        panel.add(creatorTextField);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My problem is that every FocusListener block is nearly identical to the others, but for a specific parameter.

This practice doesn't support readability, writeability, maintainability, or really any style guideline. Though there are only three blocks now, which isn't too bad, a `Glob` is going to end up with about a dozen parameters, so I'd like to solve this problem before heading too far down the wrong path.

I'd much rather create a new class which implements `FocusListener`, which takes in a `JTextField` (and/or whatever else it may need) and modifies its respective `Glob` parameter, but I don't know the proper practice if I need to modify a different variable in each one. Is there a way to generalize a `Listener` so that I don't need nearly identical code littered throughout my project?

Comment: IMO the whole interaction model of your application currently is flawed. This makes it difficult to actually review the code instead of the interaction model. I'd expect this `UpdaterGUI` to only write values when I "commit" them, instead of on an unfocus event. That makes the whole mess of Focus listeners unnecessary...

Comment: I understand, but I've been asked to hook it up to a loseFocus event. The users would like to be able to enter a value then tab away to update their field. This also lets them change the glob number and just tab through the other 3 textboxes to update a glob with the same info as the last (which they'd do a lot).

Comment: Just as an FYI Swing is really old and discouraged for new applications. You're recommended to use JavaFX which is the new thing since Java 6(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple potential issues with the code beside the duplication of code in focus listeners that you mention:

- you treat the text the user typed into a text field as a key of map that contains the Gobs without checking if such key exists - what will happen when the user types a nonexisting key?
- the name of the texfield that identifies the Gob (`gobNumber`) indicates that the gob is identified by a numerical value, yet the key of the map is a `String`. Either a numerical value should be used as the key of the map or the textfield could be renamed to avoid the confusion

To deal with the duplication - a basic way of generalizing the focus listeners would be to use the [Template method pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method). You could extract the code that would be duplicated for each listener to an abstract class and then delegate the parts that would be different to a specific subclass.

```
public abstract class UpdateGobFocusListener implements FocusListener
{
    private final Map<String, Glob> globs;
    private final JTextField globNumberTextField;

    public UpdateGobFocusListener(Map<String, Glob> globs, JTextField globNumberTextField)
    {
        this.globs = globs;
        this.globNumberTextField = globNumberTextField;
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
    {
        Glob glob = globs.get(globNumberTextField.getText());
        updateGlob(glob);
    }

    protected abstract void updateGlob(Glob glob);

}
```

And an example of a subclass:

```
public class DateGlobUpdater extends UpdateGobFocusListener
{

    private final JTextField dateTextField;

    public DateGlobUpdater(JTextField dateTextField, Map<String, Glob> globs, JTextField globNumberTextField)
    {
        super(globs, globNumberTextField);
        this.dateTextField = dateTextField;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateGlob(Glob glob)
    {
        glob.date = dateTextField.getText();
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), you could extract the duplicated code to a general focus listener, create a `GobUpdater` interface and then move the different parts to a separate implementation of the interface each. The general focus listener could be injected with the specific implementation through a constructor.